# How to freeze current library/framework versions? (Swift, XCode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a project - iOS application. I would like to store this project for later so that it is buildable in the future. I would like to freeze (save) current versions of native frameworks used in app like CoreData, CloudKit, etc.

I used Pod as a dependency manager, which downloaded the whole 3rd party libraries. Is it possible to do this with native libraries? Is there a different way to achieve this?

What should I use if I want to save the project for later but the versions of libraries might change in months or years.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can’t do it. The frameworks are externalities. You would need to maintain that same version of Xcode itself, and even perhaps a computer to run it.

Comment: It's safe to assume Apple frameworks remain backwards compatible for a very long time. I have no problem building all kinds of 5+ years old apps.